# Chaining imperative methods

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have 2 apex methods : method 1 and method 2.. I simply want to call method 2 when method 1 imperative call has been done.

As per my understanding, imperative methods return promise (that's why we use .then() ) and therefore I should be able to simply call method 2 from method 1's .then().

Is it the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

In LWC, we have an easier way: [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Using that, we can do this:

```
async someMethod() {
  let result1 = await method1();
  let result2 = await method2({param:result1});
}
```

This abbreviated syntax makes it super-simple to make code that runs asynchronously look like synchronous calls. Note that you can still try-catch if you need to worry about exceptions:

```
async someMethod() {
  try {
    let result1 = await method1();
    let result2 = await method2({param:result1});
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

`await` uses `Promise` under the hood; if the returned promise resolves, its resolution is used as the return value, if it rejects, the error is thrown as a normal exception. The `async` word is required for any method that uses await.

Comment: Dang, I forgot about that! Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

To literally chain imperative calls, with one using the results of the other, invoke the second call from within the `then` handler of the first imperative call's promise. This implies that the second imperative call's promise handling is nested within that outer promise handler too.

There are, of course, options to flatten promise handling, but that isn't appropriate when you need the results of one as inputs to another.